# How to find the size of a HDFS file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How to find the size of a HDFS file? What command should be used to find the size of any file in HDFS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `hadoop fs -ls` command to list files in the current directory as well as their details. The 5th column in the command output contains file size in bytes.

For e.g. command `hadoop fs -ls input` gives following output:

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup      45956 2012-07-19 20:57 /user/hduser/input/sou
```

The size of file `sou` is 45956 bytes.

Comment: How would you output the size in the human readable form? -ls - lah doesn't work here

Comment: How can we check space usage per user xxxx?

Comment: @ivan_bilan - hadoop fs -ls -h works. Multiple options have to be specified separately, i.e. hadoop fs -ls -R -h for specifying recursive

Answer (score 37):

I also find myself using `hadoop fs -dus <path>` a great deal. For example, if a directory on HDFS named "/user/frylock/input" contains 100 files and you need the total size for all of those files you could run:

```
hadoop fs -dus /user/frylock/input
```

and you would get back the total size (in bytes) of all of the files in the "/user/frylock/input" directory.

Also, keep in mind that HDFS stores data redundantly so the actual physical storage used up by a file might be 3x or more than what is reported by `hadoop fs -ls` and `hadoop fs -dus`.

Comment: Additionally to the last point - the replication factor is the number shown after the permissions flags, and before the owner (2nd column in @adhunavkulkarni's answer)

Comment: hadoop fs -du -s <path> for newer versions

Comment: Use `hadoop fs -du -s -h /user/frylock/input` for a much more readable output.

Comment: @axiom it returns `10.5 G  31.6 G  /path`  what are these 2 sizes

Comment: @DulangaHeshan - 10.5G is the actual (raw size of the file) and 31.6 G is the space it consumes on disk including replication which in this case is 3 ( 10.5 * 3) = ~31.6 G

Answer (score 16):

I used the below function which helped me to get the file size.

```
public class GetflStatus
{
    public long getflSize(String args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        Path path = new Path(args);
        FileSystem hdfs = path.getFileSystem(config);
        ContentSummary cSummary = hdfs.getContentSummary(path);
        long length = cSummary.getLength();
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if this returns 7906 then what is the size of that directory? Is it in bytes or in kbs?

Comment: @sandipchandanshive It probably gives you in bytes

Answer (score 9):

See the command below with awk script to see the size (in GB) of filtered output in HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -du -s /data/ClientDataNew/**A***  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.3fGB\n", s/1000000000}'
```

output ---> 2.089GB

```
hadoop fs -du -s /data/ClientDataNew/**B***  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.3fG\n", s/1000000000}'
```

output ---> 1.724GB

```
hadoop fs -du -s /data/ClientDataNew/**C***  | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf  "%.3fG\n", s/1000000000}'
```

output ---> 0.986GB

Answer (score 6):

```
hdfs dfs -du -s -h /directory
```

This is the human readable version, otherwise it will give in bad units (slight bigger)

Comment: How can we check space usage per user or for user xxxx?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it through the API, you can use 'getFileStatus()' method.

Comment: It's not right it doesn't return file size it return allocated block size which won't be zero for empty files.The default is 67108864.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to know the each files size inside the directory then use the **'*'** asterisk at the end.

```
hadoop fs -du -s -h /tmp/output/*
```

I hope this helps your purpose.