# HDFS -df command showing whole cluster regardless of path provided

Tags: hadoop

I have an Hadoop cluster and within it I have a path that, when filled, causes a lot of problems. I want to write a script that checks the usage/capacity of the path for review on a semiweekly basis. My command and results:

```
$ hdfs dfs -df -h /my/fat/directory 
Filesystem                   Size     Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://TheServer         866.9 T  593.7 T    242.4 T   68%
```

Regardless of path provided I get the usage for the entire cluster rather than the considerably smaller directory I'm worried about.

How can I get the disk usage for my directory?

EDIT:

To clarify I want the capacity of the directory and the usage. Not just the usage. -du is not acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the size of a HDFS file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574410/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-hdfs-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was looking for was the [quota](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsQuotaAdminGuide.html) set on the directory.

`hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /path/to/dir/`

Answer (score 1):

Try with below

`hdfs dfs -du -s -h /path/to/dir` or `hadoop fs -du -s -h /path/to/dir`

Check with below for capacity

`hdfs dfs -du -h /path/to/dir`

Comment: This shows file usage and doesn't indicate capacity.